# 'How comes it' or 'How come is it'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I was reading this [paper](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~dresher/Meno.pdf) and I came across this sentence, which I found quite odd.

> In the words of Bertrand Russell, the problem is this: “How comes it that human beings, whose contacts with the world are brief and personal and limited, are able to know as much as they do know?”

Shouldn't it be 'How come is it' ? It just doesn't sound right, maybe because I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Why was this down voted, just want to know. Is it something trivial ? Should I ask this question somewhere else?

Comment: I have no idea why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. *How come is it* doesn't make sense.

*How comes it* is an example of an older syntax of English, which you can find readily in sources such as Shakespeare and the King James Bible. In modern speech this has been entirely replaced by *How does it come*, but we still use the older syntax with auxiliaries: *how is it*, *how can you* etc.

I think that in Russell's day, though this form was in general obsolete, *how comes it* had survived as a literary idiom.

Comment: PDE syntax, at least in informal registers, is more likely to run to *"How come* human beings ... are able ..."

Comment: @BrianDonovan That's a different meaning, though it originates in the same metaphor: *How come?* asks "Why?", but *How comes it* asks *How?*.

Comment: @StoneyB, try the substitution of one for the other in Russell's question as a whole, and see if you still think there's much difference in meaning.

Answer (score -2):

Old English. Still not uncommon as a form of intellectual prose.

Edit: I should say outdated English. Old English would be like:

> How cometh that human beings...

Comment: No, that would be (early) **Modern English, *not* Old English.** Examples of Old English uses of the verb ***come*** include *Đonne þu cymes to me* and *Cymeð dæʒ his* and *Wæs Hæsten þa þær cumen* and *Sunnan leoma cymeþ scynan* and *Þonne ic cume ic hit forʒylde þe* and *ʒe··þe þus brontne ceol ofer lagustræte lædan cwomon* and *Æfter þam to his leode cuom··and ymb ii ʒear þæs þe he in Francum com he ʒefór.*  **See the difference now?**

Comment: No. That would be Early Modern English as to *cometh*, and Modern English as to *human being*, first attested after the Restoration.