# Meaning of the quote by Helena Christensen

Tags: quotes

I was born in high heels and I’ve worn them ever since- Helena Christensen

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of literature.

Comment: @tchrist, the person being quoted ranks rather among the glitterati than among the literati. We often ask for more context, so the whole of a sentence (one that appears on various "quotes" sites) should be welcome. But your objection seems as if it could just as easily apply to *any* sentence a questioner might ask about, if it appears either in print or on the Web--in which case it seems this site's occupation's gone.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I thought this was from a book.

Comment: @tchrist: If it were, should that disqualify it from consideration? [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186312) quotes a sentence by Bertrand Russell that appears in six books, per Google Books: were you the mystery downvoter on that account? (But I fear that every day and in every way we are getting meta and meta and meta.)

Comment: The shrieks from the birthing room must have been horrible to hear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it only allows primarily opinion-based answers unless the speaker is contacted.

Comment: @Erik Kowal The less publicised side of Dr Steptoe's work?

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a particularly overt example of [hyperbole](http://humanities.byu.edu/rhetoric/Figures/H/hyperbole.htm) (rhetorical exaggeration) in expressing partiality to high heels, or perhaps in noting or complaining that her path in life has long forced them upon her. The hyperbole is overt in that no one can be expected to take this literally, especially its first clause. In fact, this [*Daily Mail* piece](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2620364/Helena-Christensens-son-Mingus-14-taller-supermodel-mother.html) shows her in photographs wearing flats, and twits her on supposedly needing to wear heels more often.

Comment: You’re actually linking to the Daily Mail? :(

Comment: Well, having no idea who this person was, I thought it prudent to Google her before venturing an answer; and this was among the top hits and seemed peculiarly on point, with photographic evidence to boot (pun intended, as always).

Comment: You know, it could also mean that she's symbolically a girly-girl and the high heels represent the trappings of an ultra-feminine woman.  Since both your and my speculations are opinion-based, this question should be off-topic.

Comment: I'm surprised at how many people here seem to never have heard of Helena Christensen before.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I think I allowed for that interpretive possibility--and the point that it is hyperbole is hardly mere speculation.