# A rural dialect for "Why"?

Tags: phrases, translation, dialects

Forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask about this.

For context, I've been trying to figure out a good way to translate "なしてや", which is a [dialect of どうして and なぜ](https://cherish-media.jp/posts/6533). All of them mean "why, how".

In this instance, I have a character trying to correct her speech from "rural-sounding" to more "urban-sounding".

> り: ......なら、参謀になりたい。
>
> R: ......So, I should just join the military.
>
> あ: 参謀！？なしてや！？あ、じゃなくって、なんでですかっ？
>
> A: The military!? [rural dialect of why]!? Ah, I mean, why?

In order to keep the same meaning in English, I would need to find some equivalent of なしてや, keeping the dialect and all.

The options I've come up so far are

- "What in tarnation!? Ah, I mean, why?"
- "Whycome!? Ah, I mean, why(/how come)?"
- "What in the Lord's name!? Ah, I mean, why?"

I don't think these are "natural" enough. For the last one, it doesn't seem in character for her to be using that phrase.

So exactly what is a good way to translate this dialect to English? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never heard of "whycome". Not sure about the context, or what "rural" really means. I suggest [WTF](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wtf) which is impolite modern idiom & slang.

Comment: @WeatherVane By "rural" I mean by a country accent, if that makes sense. The character isn't the type to swear like that (That's more of R's thing), so it wouldn't work out. Regarding "whycome", that's how one person translated the phrase, which is a bit strange, but it's something.

Comment: Perhaps the translater meant "how come...?" Please see [Why is it “how come” and not “why come”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33938/why-is-it-how-come-and-not-why-come) I suggested WTF as the urban version, not the rural. I have no understanding of the unnamed language used in the question.

Comment: So it depends on which dialect you want. Would "howzat" work?

Comment: @MrLister It could work, in a sense. Though, doesn't that mean "How's that"? It does sound more common than the three I came up with, however.

Comment: The longest sentence posted is given by google translate as "Staff! ? No way! ? Oh, why not?"

Comment: @WeatherVane Google Translate isn't that great for these sort of things. My translation is more akin to the actual tone of the dialogue. "No way" is extremely common in any setting, so I wouldn't classify that for "country-sounding".

Comment: "No way!" is a great expression in response to a suggestion that someone should join the military. Why can't you use it?

Comment: @WeatherVane Because it's common in any setting and not exactly specific to the countryside. It would erase the meaning of said character trying to correct her speech.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Mitch The question is not asking about a Japanese word or the meaning of a Japanese sentence; it’s asking about an English word, with quite a specific meaning and context. It would be completely off-topic on Japanese.SE, but is completely on-topic here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't know Japanese.SE, but I suspect that they are more likely to be better at translations to English than here. There are alternates to 'Why': how come, what for, that are slightly less formal than 'why', maybe those will work?

Comment: なしてや doesn't literally translate into English (and of course you know that), but it seems to me what you're looking for is a way to translate the rough manners of a country bumpkin (perhaps 芋兄さん) into more polite speech. Without going deeply into the differences between the two societies, I'd suggest you start with an abbreviated crudity and break off in the middle of it where you segue into the more acceptable, like so: "What the he—I mean, why?" (where "he" is the beginning of "hell" and is swallowed). The art is where you put the em dash interruption. "What the fu—I mean, why?" also works.

Comment: In my opinion English doesn't have another common way of asking "why" that would prompt correction, so if you want to include the concept of this character correcting their own speech to be more urbane it would be better done with another expression at some other point of the conversation. Trying to do the translation strictly word by word or phrase by phrase will not produce the most natural English version.

Comment: @Robusto Actually, that could work. I'll use that. Thank you.